# Nativescript Angular 6 - Adding Icon with String into Actionbar title

Tags: angular, typescript, android-actionbar, nativescript

Using Angular 6 with Nativescript.  For one of my pages, I want the Actionbar title to be a dropdown - so I want to show text with a down-icon. 
[image]

This is currently what I have, but I cannot seem to figure out how to add anything but the text to the actionbar title: 
```

```
<ActionBar [title]="user.userName" class="profile-head">
  <ActionItem
    ios.position="left"
    android.position="left">
        <Label
            class="fal"
            text="&#xf234;"></Label>
    </ActionItem>
  <ActionItem
    ios.position="right"
    android.position="right">
        <Label
            class="fas"
            text="&#xf013;">
        </Label>
    </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Custom TitleView](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#using-a-custom-title-view).

**Example**

```
<ActionBar title="test">
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal"
    ios:horizontalAlignment="center"
    android:horizontalAlignment="left">
    <Label text="YourTest"  class="action-label"></Label>
    <Image src="res://Your_Image" class="action-image"></Image>
  </StackLayout>
</ActionBar>
```

Comment: You are a gentlemen and a scholar, sir. Thank you kindly! Worked like a charm. I didn't realize I could use this in conjunction with the other actionitems. Thank you!